# Z-score calculation on rolling window

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

How can I calculate z-score on 2 days rolling window with my data as below in pandas dataframe?

I also want to group by on class name.

| Date | Class | Marks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2022 | A | 1700 |
| 02-01-2022 | A | 3000 |
| 03-01-2022 | A | 2624 |
| 04-01-2022 | A | 1745 |
| 05-01-2022 | A | 1789 |
| 06-01-2022 | A | 1874 |
| 01-01-2022 | B | 1965 |
| 02-01-2022 | B | 1847 |
| 03-01-2022 | B | 1849 |
| 04-01-2022 | B | 1754 |
| 05-01-2022 | B | 1598 |
| 06-01-2022 | B | 1515 |
| 01-01-2022 | C | 433 |
| 02-01-2022 | C | 350 |
| 03-01-2022 | C | 268 |
| 04-01-2022 | C | 433 |
| 05-01-2022 | C | 350 |
| 06-01-2022 | C | 268 |

I tried this.

```
my_data['zscore'] = (my_data['Marks']-(my_data['Marks'].rolling(2).mean()))/(my_data['Marks'].rolling(2).std())
```

Comment: Remember that `lambda` is just an anonymous function. You can always define a separate function and use it as `apply` method parameter. So you can use lambda or a separate function.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
def func(x):
    return np.mean(x)/np.std(x)
```

then:

```
my_data['Marks'].rolling(2).apply(func)
```

Or:

```
my_data['Marks'].rolling(2).apply(lambda x: np.mean(x)/np.std(x))
```

Based on your comment, use:

```
string = """Date    Class   Marks
01-01-2022  A   1700
02-01-2022  A   3000
03-01-2022  A   2624
04-01-2022  A   1745
05-01-2022  A   1789
06-01-2022  A   1874
01-01-2022  B   1965
02-01-2022  B   1847
03-01-2022  B   1849
04-01-2022  B   1754
05-01-2022  B   1598
06-01-2022  B   1515
01-01-2022  C   433
02-01-2022  C   350
03-01-2022  C   268
04-01-2022  C   433
05-01-2022  C   350
06-01-2022  C   268"""
temp = [x.split('   ') for x in string.split('\n')]
df=pd.DataFrame(temp[1:], columns = temp[0])
df.groupby('Class')['Marks'].apply(lambda x: np.mean(x)/np.std(x))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way I can group the calculation for each class name separately? The above code is taking different classes(A,B,C) as one.